# Using AOP for opening and closing connections to database

Tags: c#, java, php, language-agnostic, aop

It's good practice to use AOP for opening and closing DB connections? I want to use AOP in my DAO classes.

For example, inside method `public User createUser(String name)` I don't want to write code like `Connection.open()` and `Connection.close()`, I want to do it automatically, using aspects.

Answer (score 1):

It makes perfect sense to do so as long as people using your methods and the API will be *aware* that the method initialises the connection and, even more importantly, closes it afterwards. There are some things which needs considerations, though.

Think about API's consistency. Do all methods open and close connections? If not, why some don't and what should you do to make it clear that they don't to people using the API?

Remember to put error handling into consideration. When an error occurs, e.g. an exception it thrown, the state of the connection after the method exits should be unambigouos.

Keep reentrancy in mind. If a method can be executed from multiple threads and it affects the global state you're dangerously close to a recipe for a disaster. Make it secure and make it understandable.

On a side note, rethink closing connections after each method call. Does opening and closing a connection each time you add a row into the database make sense? Performance-wise it's more reasonable to reuse the connection for further queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ORM, like Hibernate or Eclipselink, coupled with Spring and Transactions / AOP, it takes care of everything for you.

You should never have to write Connection.open with a good persistence framework.  There are plenty to choose from these days.

Aspects make a ton of sense in Java for things like logging, security, and caching.  But I would leave the persistence stuff to the persistence library.  They are incredibly mature and very reliable.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web application, you might want to use a session-per-request pattern. You can use an HttpModule or ActionFilter to do this. I would consider that to be an AOP approach without a 3rd-party AOP framework.

See also: [How can I implement a robust session-per-request pattern in my project, while focusing on information hiding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046168/how-can-i-implement-a-robust-session-per-request-pattern-in-my-project-while-fo)